# get page source code after redirection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I tried some ways to get the page source code of the following website `http://www.poppe-bedrijfswagens.nl`. This website has a auto redirection set I think.

I tried following ways:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string sourceCode = "";
sourceCode = client.DownloadString(address);
```

And

```
HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(address);
myWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
myWebRequest.Method = "GET";

// make request for web page
HttpWebResponse myWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myWebRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader myWebSource = new StreamReader(myWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
string myPageSource = myWebSource.ReadToEnd();
myWebResponse.Close();
```

I always get the source code of the first page but i need to get the source code of the page that the website redirected to.

The redirection for `http://www.poppe-bedrijfswagens.nl` is:

```
Type of redirect: “meta refresh” redirect after 0 second
Redirected to: http://www.poppe-bedrijfswagens.nl/daf-html/dealer_homepage.html
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, I need the `DOCTYPE` of each website (in this example it is `http://www.poppe-bedrijfswagens.nl`). If you know a faster way to get the `DOCTYPE` of a website programmatically, you can always help me :). But the problem in this topic is different, its about redirections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AllowAutoRedirect property is relevant when the redirection is done with an HTTP status code 302. A meta refresh isn't technically a redirection because you are loading the first page.

You can download the first page though and then search the DOM for the element you're interested in `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=HTTP://WWW.NEXT-URL.COM">` and then download the page you're interested in.